# Delete all associations from duplicated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

When duplicating an object with `object_dup = object.dup`, all associations are copied.

```
object_dup.foos == object.foos
```

I would like to duplicate/clone `object` without its associations, or delete the associations all after duplication. I would like to destroy all duplicated associations on `object_dup`. It might be easier to just create a new object, but duplication saves me from property-setting-hell.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `.dup` method didn't duplicate associations, it just copy the foreign key (parents).

Examples:

```
# Original
my_post = Post.first
=> #<Post id: 1, title: 'blabla', category_id: 10>

# Duplicate
my_post.dup
=> #<Post id: nil, title: 'blabla', category_id: 10>

# Have the same category_id (10)
```

My best way to duplicate without some attributes :

```
Post.new(my_post.attributes.slice('titles'))
=> #<Post id: nil, title: 'blabla', category_id: nil>
```

Here we creating a new empty `Post`, get original post attributes with `my_post.attributes` and slice only attributes we want with `slice('title')` (accept multiples attributes, examples: `slice('title', 'content', 'tags')`)

[.dup Documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup)

[.slice Documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice)

Comment: Ah thanks:Yes reading the docs helps i missed that part with the foriegn key;)